# Check Password Reset Key Not Woking

Tags: password, reset

I am trying create passowrd reset form. Here is my function:

```
<?php 
$user_data = get_user_by( 'email', 'admin@mysite.com' ) );
$key = get_password_reset_key( $user_data );
$user_login = $user_data->user_login;

$message = esc_url( get_permalink( '1' ) . "?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login) ) . "\r\n";

wp_mail( $user_email, "Title", $message );
?>
```

It sends reset link to my mail, with $key and $login. It is ok.

Now i must check the reset key. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$errors = new WP_Error();
$user = check_password_reset_key($_GET['key'], $_GET['login']);

if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
    if ( $user->get_error_code() === 'expired_key' )
        echo "Key is expired";
    else
        echo "Key is not valid";
}
?>
```

But it always says **Key is not valid**. Where is wrong?

Comment: In the `else`, try to `echo` the `$user->get_error_message()` instead of "*Key is not valid*", and see what it says.

Comment: It says **invalid key** @Sally

Comment: Try `$user = check_password_reset_key($_GET['key'], rawurldecode($_GET['login']));` because you `rawurlencode()` the `login` in the email. If that doesn't work, do `var_dump( $_GET['key'], $_GET['login'] );` and see if the values are valid.

Comment: Yes. I found the problem. Php is not reads $_GET valuse. Because url is wrong.
http://localhost/wordpress/reset-pass-page//?action=rp&#038;key=FfmD8eWNGa9WSUhTUfot&#038;login=root
**#038;** why it add this #038; ?

Comment: Because that's how [`esc_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/) works. I.e. By default, it converts `&amp;` to `&#038;`. Sorry that I didn't really notice (or pay attention to) the `wp_mail()` part. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. We need decode url with **esc_url_raw**. Here is solution.

```
<?php 
$user_data = get_user_by( 'email', 'admin@mysite.com' ) );
$key = get_password_reset_key( $user_data );
$user_login = $user_data->user_login;

$url = esc_url_raw( get_permalink( '1' ) . "?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login) ) . "\r\n";
$message = $url;

wp_mail( $user_email, "Title", $message );
?>
```

Comment: Actually, you could just define `$url` like this: `$url = esc_url_raw( get_permalink( '1' ) . "?action=rp&key=$key&login=$user_login" );`. I.e. No need to `rawurlencode($user_login)` or do the `htmlspecialchars_decode()` part. =)

Comment: It's my pleasure helping you! =)